# nginx location root always overridden by location /

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name local.server;

    # root   /Users/username/code/project/register; 
    # Works if root defined here and location / is deleted

    location /register { # root seems to be set to location / always
        root   /Users/username/code/project/register;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        root    /Users/username/code/web/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

local.server:8000/register always try to server file from the root of location /

I want

location / -> root code/web/public

location/register -> root code/project/register

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your value for `root` is incorrect. You are pointing to `/Users/username/code/project/register/register`.

Try:

```
location /register {
    root /Users/username/code/project;
    ...
}
```

Also, the default action under `/register` is to go to `/index.html` which is under the other root. Did you mean to specify `/register/index.html`?

For example:

```
location /register {
    root /Users/username/code/project;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /register/index.html?/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. Is there a way to strip the matching regular expression though? so that I could use location ~ ^/(register) and then remove the register part of the URL, so that the angular app could still have base href as /